# Making a WPF DataGrid repeat Column Headers under each group header

Tags: wpf, datagrid, grouping, datagridcolumnheader

I'm using grouping in WPF (via PropertyGroupDescription in a CollectionViewSource) and displaying the grouped collection in a bound DataGrid.

Typically (as in [this MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126.aspx)) such a DataGrid will display the column headers, followed by each group header (defined in the GroupStyle.Containerstyle), followed by the rows of data in the given group.  Here's a quick visual:

```
 +=====================================================+
 |  ColumnHeader1  |  ColumnHeader2  |  ColumnHeader3  |
 +-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
 |  Group A                                            |
 +-----------------------------------------------------+
 |   A_Value_11    |   A_Value_12    |   A_Value_13    |
 +-----------------------------------------------------+
 |   A_Value_21    |   A_Value_22    |   A_Value_23    |
 +-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
 |  Group B                                            |
 +-----------------------------------------------------+
 |   B_Value_11    |   B_Value_12    |   B_Value_13    |
 +-----------------------------------------------------+
 |   B_Value_21    |   B_Value_22    |   B_Value_23    |
 +=====================================================+
```

Is there a way to make the DataGrid column headers appear/repeat after every group header?

Visually, this is more like what I want:

```
 +=====================================================+
 |  Group A                                            |
 +-----------------------------------------------------+
 |  ColumnHeader1  |  ColumnHeader2  |  ColumnHeader3  |
 +-----------------------------------------------------+
 |   A_Value_11    |   A_Value_12    |   A_Value_13    |
 +-----------------------------------------------------+
 |   A_Value_21    |   A_Value_22    |   A_Value_23    |
 +-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
 |  Group B                                            |
 +-----------------------------------------------------+
 |  ColumnHeader1  |  ColumnHeader2  |  ColumnHeader3  |
 +-----------------------------------------------------+
 |   B_Value_11    |   B_Value_12    |   B_Value_13    |
 +-----------------------------------------------------+
 |   B_Value_21    |   B_Value_22    |   B_Value_23    |
 +=====================================================+
```

Is it possible to do that without too much trouble?

Answer (score 0):

I would add additional first row for each group containing column headers as text and displayed it with special cell template, e.g. as TextBlock styled like typical column header.